# Display a subset of classes in axes in ggplot

Tags: r, data-mining, visualization, ggplot2

I have the following plot, is there any way in ggplot to display just the numbers 1 to 10 instead of all of them?
Numbers from 10 and after are not so important, but I need to display the ones before.
Thank you

[image: My plot]

Comment: the easy fix ( if numbers after 10 are not need) is to filter data to have N from 1 to 10 and plot this data

Comment: have you tryed adding the scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1, 10)) ? Is part of ggplot2 so make sure you run install.packages "ggplot2"and right after run library(ggplot2) Let me know if that helps. Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this kind of wor around, but if you have another solution, please enlighten me :)

```
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = N%>% as.factor())) +
  xlab(label = 'N') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, size = 8))
```

[image]